# Terminal message: .zshrc:1: no such file or directory:

Tags: macos, file, terminal, directory, zshrc

Every time I open the terminal, this message appears:

> Last login: Sat Apr 17 22:09:11 on ttys000
> /Users/johnrimestad/.zshrc:1: no such file or directory: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

What should I do?
I use MacOS 11.2.3. Zsh is my default shell, but I had a .bashrc file, so I created one .zshrc also.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The content of my .zshrc file looks like this: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

And my .bashrc file: 
/Users/johnrimestad/Library/Python/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.3:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/johnrimestad/.nimble/bin:$PATH